# Is there a word or phrase meaning "using the character limit to the maximum"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I know there is a word for getting exactly one result in the SERP of google. But is there a word for making a comment here or a tweet that exactly fills the permitted space? I.e., a "0 (zero) character left" tweet or comment that is exactly as long as the maximum length?

For example, my recent comment that was getting long so I had to modify it to fit exactly with 0 characters left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that they ***[maxed out](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/max%20out)*** on the number of usable characters:

> to reach an upper limit or a peak

[Merriam-Webster]

Comment: Yes! In Stockholm we say "That is (=Det är...) _maxat_"

Answer (score 3):

**'Filled to the brim'** might be the word you are looking for.

Comment: Good catch. But "brimmed" is a better option.